# Why firebase custom domain don't return index.html?

Tags: firebase, dns, http-status-code-404, hosting

I have a proyect in firebase, with two custom domains, as show de [image firebase console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE7f5.png)

With the fist one, [colademonofrozen.cl/](https://colademonofrozen.cl/) I get index.html file OK, but with the second, [www.colademonofrozen.cl/](https://www.colademonofrozen.cl/) I get 404 not found.

Some strange thing about this case is that [www.colademonofrozen.cl/anything](https://www.colademonofrozen.cl/anything) display index.html file OK.

This is the hosting configuration:
`

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app",
        "region": "us-central1" 
      },
      {
        "source": "/admin",
        "destination": "/admin.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

`

I worked a lot for this project, I really appreciate any ideas.

I also appreciate anyone confirming that the domain shows an error page, so the problem cannot be ignored if it starts working.

- I confirmed that it is not a cache problem.
- The subdomain is configured more than two weeks ago, is not time propagation problem.
- I requested a redirect at my dns provider, from the subdomain  [www.colademonofrozen.cl/](https://www.colademonofrozen.cl/) to [colademonofrozen.cl/](https://colademonofrozen.cl/), but is not posible if the domain points to Firebase.

To my bad luck, the back label of the product for which I created the project are already printed.
[see back label!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Hic.png)

Comment: Might be on your end. The `www` endpoint works for me.

Comment: Works fine for me as well

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander N. and Kimbo for your answers. I have tried with different browsers, PCs and mobile devices in my city (Santiago de Chile), including PCs that have never requested the page. I always get 404 not found. I do not know what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change following DNS record:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| www.colademonofrozen.cl. | CNAME | colademonofrozen.cl |

for:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| www.colademonofrozen.cl. | A | 199.36.158.100 |

Now works OK.